# uniform variables same in opengl

Tags: glsl, uniform

I have two variables that I'm getting from shader in opengl. I do something like this.

```
    vLoc = glGetAttribLocation(progId,"vPosition");
    nLoc = glGetAttribLocation(progId,"vNormal");

matViewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(progId,"matView");
matProjLoc = glGetUniformLocation(progId,"matProj");
matTranslateLoc = glGetUniformLocation(progId,"matTranslate");
```

vLoc and projLoc return the same location. Would anybody know why? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The space for uniform locations and attribute locations is different, so you can have same IDs, but they refer to different objects.

You can't pass a attribute location to a glUniform function or a uniform location to a attrib function.

Answer (score 0):

did you bind the attrib location when you created the shader program using glBindAttribLocation?

You need something like this:

```
glBindAttribLocation(progId, 0, "vPosition");
glBindAttribLocation(progId, 1, "vNormal");
```

Comment: No I never did in any of my other programs and they all worked. I put it right after vLoc and nLoc but still nothing.